# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/learning/avionSave] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

I am receiving still this problem:
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/learning/avionSave] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
After pressing AvionNew button in my avion.jsp page.

The project works like: it will load home page, where I will redirect to avion.jsp page by clocking on avion button. There will appear new button called AvionNew. When I will press this button, I want it to load @RequestMapping(value = "/avionSave" .. and print to console just System.out.println("are we here?");
But its not working and it still shows me that error :(

This is my home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>

<a href="http://localhost:8080/learning/">Home</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/learning/avion">Avion</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my avion.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Avion</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Nazdar  
</h1>

${hodnota}


<a href="http://localhost:8080/learning/">Home</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/learning/avion">Avion</a>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/learning/avionSave" name=odkaz>AvionNew</a>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my HomeController.java:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/avion", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String avion(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("hodnota", "here");
        System.out.println("still here...");
        return "avion";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/avionSave", method = RequestMethod.GET,params="odkaz")
    public String avionOdkaz(Locale locale, Model model) {
        System.out.println("are we here?");
        return "avion";
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my root-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

</beans>
```

This is my servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dodo.learning" />



</beans:beans>
```

I was googling a lot, saw lots of topics similar to this, but i was not able to fix it :(
Could someone please help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: share servlet-context.xml

Comment: Are you deploying your application under root context or `/learning` to your tomcat? And please add your `root-context.xml` and `servlet-context.xml` files

Comment: I have added root context and servlet context to the topic.

If I am deployoing it? Hm I am running it on my localhost using tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing the wrong context-path. Using Tomcat you can see on startup something like this on the log

```
OK - Deployed application at context path /foo
```

So you can know the context of your application.